# Non-standard grammar feature in British dialect?

Tags: grammar, british-english, dialects, non-standard

I moved from Worcestershire in the UK to a non-native English speaking country when I was a child, which has made me very aware of my accent. Unlike my parents, I used to have a regional accent. I feel that accent was easy to understand for most British English speakers. However, I use some features that I don't recall hearing anyone else use.

One noticeable feature to me is the differentiation of singular and plural nouns even when they are spelled identically, by repeating the vowel sound in the first syllable (or the first part of the vowel if it's a diphthong). So for example:

- singular *sheep* /'ʃeɪp/
- plural *sheep* /ʃe'heɪp/ or /ʃe'ʔeɪp/
- singular *muffin* /'mɤfɪŋ/
- plural *muffins* /mɤ'hɤfɪŋz/ or /mɤ'ʔɤfɪŋz/

I'm not entirely sure about this second part, but I think I also use this vowel repetition for partitives.

Eg. "piece" is pronounced /'peɪs/, but "a /pe'ʔeɪs/ of bread"

Has anyone heard this single/plural vowel-repetition used in the UK or elsewhere?

Comment: I've heard duplicated vowel sounds in the South-East Derbyshire dialect, but not to indicate the plural (for instance, the names Jean and Kyle pronounced 'Jeeun' and 'Ki-ull').

Comment: Phonological variation across the UK. https://www.bl.uk/british-accents-and-dialects/articles/phonological-variation-across-the-uk

Comment: Do you have any recordings of someone talking this way?